# What are the minimal iptables rules to surf the internet?

Tags: linux, security

I am trying to set minimal rules to my Linux iptables rules file to just be able to surf the internet.

Here what I did:

```
* filter

-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

With just those rules, I can't surf the web.

I noticed that when I put `-A INPUT -j ACCEPT`, it works but I don't understand why. 
So what Input/output port do I need to surf the internet?

Thanks a lot. Regards

**EDIT**: It still doesn't work.

here is my `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
blank

Chain OUTPUT (Policy ACCEPT)
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere
```

However, if I add `-A INPUT -j ACCEPT`, I can surf the internet. So there should be something else within INPUT that's preventing it.

Comment: Does it still not work, now that you have changed "ACCEPTED" to "ACCEPT"?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the bottom of my post with the `iptables -L`. Thanks. Regards

Comment: You technically needn't set any at all (nor drop policies).  Nonetheless, I fear this is off topic here, as it doesn't appear to be about professional system administration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to allow traffic that's returning from the remote servers, as well.  Your input chain needs to allow those responses; the connection state module can make sure those responses are allowed.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried your way. It seems to have worked for a few seconds, then I still get the same problem. I used `iptables-save` to extract the rules as they appear. I put them at the end of my post. Thanks a lot if you could tell me what is wrong. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 I'm not seeing your rules in the `OUTPUT` chain anymore?  Those are still needed in order for the connection to be allowed in the first place.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a reason why `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT` is not enough? I thought that I wouldn't need those OUTPUT rules, if I accept all OUTPUT packets. Thanks.

Comment: @alexx0186 Oh, yes - I didn't notice that you'd changed that; that should work fine.  Though now that I look closer your new rule set says `-j ACCEPTED` instead of `-j ACCEPT`; typo?

Comment: Hi, sorry it was just a typo on my post. There seems to be something else as INPUT that should be set in addition to the `state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule, because if I add `-A INPUT -j ACCEPT` as a rule, I can surf the internet. Thanks a lot for your help. Regards

Answer (score 5):

Why exactly do you feel the need to regulate outbound connections?

The OUTPUT table manages OUTBOUND packets, and the INPUT table manages inbound packets.

If you're looking to secure your workstation/server, you should focus on INPUT rules and use a default 'DROP' rule and a 'RELATED,ESTABLISHED' rule like this one:

```
 /sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow you to then open additional specific ports while keeping most traffic out.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in /etc/sysconfig/iptables (your IPtables rule file)

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Some time iptables-save didn't work for me,It shows that it is save by restarting iptables service returned it to previous stage

Comment: Hi Shariq, thanks for your answer.  This question already has an almost identical answer to yours that was marked as being correct over a year ago.  I'm also not seeing anything in this question to indicate that the OP is running a RedHat-derived system and hence even *has* an `/etc/sysconfig/` directory.